# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_erase'

Tags: python, attributeerror, livewires

I am trying to make a game where you have to avoid objects falling from the sky. I am a beginner programmer (14yrs old) so I make a lot of mistakes. I solve all of them(for this program) but i dont know how to fix this one. The error is in title. Thank you.
Full code:

```
from livewires import games, color
import random

games.init(screen_width = 1280, screen_height = 720, fps = 150)

class Covjek(games.Sprite):
    def update(self):
        if self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.destroy()
            games.screen.quit()
        self.x = games.mouse.x
        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0
        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.right = games.screen.width

class Budala(games.Sprite):
    odds_change = 200
    def __init__(self, y = 50, speed = 2, odds_change = 200):
        super(Budala, self).__init__(image = games.load_image("nigga.jpg"),
                                 x = games.screen.width/2,
                                 y = y,
                                 dx = speed)
        self.odds_change = odds_change
        self.time = 200
        self.score = 0
        games.screen.add(self.score)
        self.text = games.Text(size = 50, x = games.screen.width - 20,
                               y = games.screen.height - 20, value = self.score,
                               color = color.red)    

    def update(self):
        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        if self.left < 0:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        odd = random.randrange(Budala.odds_change + 1)
        if odd == Budala.odds_change:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        self.time -= 1
        if self.time == 0:
            games.screen.add(Meteor(image = games.load_image("smeg.jpg"),
                                     x = self.x,
                                     y = self.y,
                                     dy = 2))
            self.time = 200



class Meteor (games.Sprite):

def __init__(self, chef, x = 640, y = 670,image = games.load_image("kamijonhehe.jpg")):
    super(Meteor, self).__init__(x = x,
                                  image = image,
                                  y = y,
                                  chef = budala)
    self.chef = chef
def update(self):
    if self.bottom > games.screen.height:
        self.destroy()
        self.chef.score += 1

games.screen.background = games.load_image("boaj.jpg")
budala = Budala()
games.screen.add(budala)                                      
games.screen.add(Covjek(image = games.load_image("kamijonhehe.jpg"),
                        x = games.screen.width/2,
                        bottom = 720))
games.screen.event_grab = True
games.mouse.is_visible = False
games.music.load("smukwed.mp3")
games.music.play()
games.music.play()
games.screen.mainloop()
```

Full error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nikol\Desktop\Python\prugrami limun\izbegavalje.py", line 
75, in <module>
    games.screen.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py", line 303, in 
mainloop
    object._erase()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_erase'
```

P.S. some of the words are in Serbian so they could be hard to remember.
Working in Python 3.1, pygame 1.9.1 and livewires. Line games.screen.mainloop() is throwing the error.

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Hi @Nicola! Please, post a traceback (formatted as code as well). Now your code is not runnable (because there's no source .jpg files, at least), so we can't reproduce an error and help you to fix it. So you'll help us to answer if provide a stacktrace

Comment: @MikhailStepanov i posted it the second you asked for it