# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_erase' Python 3.1

Tags: python, attributeerror, livewires

I am working in Python 3.1 and I want to make a game of avoiding falling objects. I always get a module error.

My livewires is 1.9.1..

```
games.screen.background = games.load_image("boaj.jpg")
budala = Budala()
games.screen.add(budala)                                      
games.screen.add(Covjek(image = games.load_image("kamijonhehe.jpg"),
                        x = games.screen.width/2,
                        bottom = 720))
games.screen.event_grab = True
games.mouse.is_visible = False
games.music.load("smukwed.mp3")
games.music.play()
games.music.play()
games.screen.mainloop()
```

full error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nikol\Desktop\Python\prugrami limun\izbegavalje.py", line 
71, in <module>
    games.screen.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py", line 303, in 
mainloop
    object._erase()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_erase'
```

if you need a full code ask in the comments

Comment: you indeed have to at least provide the code of mainloop() to get any help!

Comment: @B.Go already did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '\_erase'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364148/attributeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-erase)